# hadoop cluster datanodes cannot be connected:all nodes has the same hostname is ok or not?

Tags: hadoop

I am now establishing a hadoop cluster(4 machines including 1 master to run namenode and jobTracker,  3 slaves to run dataNode and TaskTraker ).But it is a pitty that all the datanode cannot be connected.I run `sudo netstat -ntlp` on master machine,result is:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52193           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39267           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7284/rpc.mountd 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33219           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7284/rpc.mountd 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1539/mongos     
tcp6       0      0 :::50030                :::*                    LISTEN      604/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::57134                :::*                    LISTEN      32646/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      13786/rpcbind   
tcp6       0      0 :::57428                :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::57173                :::*                    LISTEN      7284/rpc.mountd 
tcp6       0      0 :::50070                :::*                    LISTEN      32646/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::5910                 :::*                    LISTEN      2452/Xvnc       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      32473/sshd      
tcp6       0      0 :::50744                :::*                    LISTEN      7284/rpc.mountd 
tcp6       0      0 :::55036                :::*                    LISTEN      14031/rpc.statd 
tcp6       0      0 :::42205                :::*                    LISTEN      7284/rpc.mountd 
tcp6       0      0 :::44289                :::*                    LISTEN      504/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::38950                :::*                    LISTEN      604/java        
tcp6       0      0 192.168.10.10:9000      :::*                    LISTEN      32646/java      
tcp6       0      0 192.168.10.10:9001      :::*                    LISTEN      604/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::50090                :::*                    LISTEN      504/java
```

And the exception message from my 3 datanodes machines are the same(of course they have different ips):
The error log for datanode 192.168.10.12:

```
2014-01-13 12:41:02,332 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2014-01-13 12:41:02,334 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2014-01-13 12:41:03,427 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: mongodb/192.168.10.12:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2014-01-13 12:41:04,427 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: mongodb/192.168.10.12:9000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2014-01-13 12:41:05,428 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: mongodb/192.168.10.12:9000. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2014-01-13 12:41:06,428 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: mongodb/192.168.10.12:9000. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
```

So ,what make me confused is that why is every datanode is trying to connect to itself?For example , the error log of datanode 192.168.10.12 shows that it is trying to connect 192.168.10.12 on port 9000,and there is no such a listening port on 12.

All my cluster nodes has the same hostname but different ips(master:192.168.10.10 slaves:192.168.10.11,192.168.10.12,192.168.10.13),All my configuration files ,including `core-site.xml`,`hdfs-site.xml` and `mapred-site.xml` use ip address directly.I use `sudo ufw status` ,it shows the firewall for all machines are `**inactive**`!

the configuration file for this 4 machines are the same(of course ip is different)：

core-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://192.168.10.12:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/var/hadoop/tmp</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
     <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
                <value>3</value>
         </property>
         <property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>/var/hadoop/name</value>
    </property>
        <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/var/hadoop/data</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
     <property>
                  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
                  <value>http://192.168.10.12:9001</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

/etc/hosts in my master::

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.10.12   mongodb
192.168.10.12   localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

in line 2 for file /etc/hosts,mongodb is the hostname of the cluster,and the hostname of other three slaves is also mongodb(Because these machines are used to be used as mongodb cluster).

I strongly suspect that it is  the tcp6 who causes the problems. So , how to start hadoop using tcp network instead of tcp6?

So ,my question is:

1.Is hadoop started in tcp6 instead of tcp  ok?

2.All the cluster machine has the same hostname but different LAN ips is ok for hadoop?

So ,any suggestions?

Comment: did you check your firewall settings?

Comment: I use sudo ufw status,it shows:inactive,for all machines.

Comment: Restart all four services (namenode,datanode,jobtracker and tasktrakcer) and then check.

What IP have you set in host file of namenode machine?

Comment: @Sudz,what do you mean by host file?I have edited my question and pasted out my /etc/hosts file of the master.

Comment: host file means the same your /etc/hosts. You need to comment first line. there is already one more entry for localhost

Comment: There is master file in  /lib/hadoop/conf/ . you need to add the ip of your namenode machine in all of your datanode master file.

Comment: @Sudz Of cource all the datanodes and namenode have the same masters file containing the ip address of the master machine.And As you said ,I comment the first line of /etc/hosts in master,error still exists.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45094/discussion-between-vico-wu-and-sudz)

Answer (score 1):

Two different mistakes leads to my problems:
1:for every core-site.xml file of 3 slaves,`the value of fs.default.name means the namenode's ip address` , thus all should   be the ip address of master , but what I write is each slave's ip address . So , when I use start-all.sh in the master , each slave is trying to connect to its own port 9000 ,instead of the master's.Since the slave is running as datanode ,instead of namenode , so connection is refused.

2: After I modified the ip address for core-site.xml for 3 slaves,although every slave becomes trying to connect to the master's port 9000 ,but connection is still refused.I run `sudo netstat -ntlp` on the master , it shows:

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9000      :::*                    LISTEN      32646/java
```

This 127.0.0.1 means that it is only listening to connection on 9000 which is from lcoalhost , all the connection on 9000 from outside cannot be received.So , problem goes to file /etc/hosts.My /ect/hosts file is below:

```
192.168.10.12   localhost
192.168.10.12   mongodb
127.0.0.1       localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Since I am using ip address in the config file ,so in such a configuration file , ip address 192.168.10.12 will be translated to host name localhost ,and I run host localhost , it show :`localhost has address 127.0.0.1`.So , such a configuration will leads to hadoop will only listening to 127.0.0.1:9000.  So , I modified this file(switch line 1 and line 2):

```
    192.168.10.12   mongodb
    192.168.10.12   localhost
    127.0.0.1       localhost

    # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I restart hadoop and `sudo netstat -ntlp` , it shows:

```
tcp6       0      0 192.168.10.10:9000      :::*                    LISTEN      32646/java
```

Every thing is ok.Since master is listening on its LAN ip address , instead of just loop back localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Your core-site.xml must have the `namenode Ip` address, and your slaves must have different hostnames in /etc/hosts.

It should work like this.